# How to replace MediaProvider in Android11

Tags: android, installation, apk

I tried to install MediaProvider in Android. But I got the following error:

```
Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to install MediaProvider.apk: Failure 
[INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.android.providers.media.module signatures do 
not match previously installed version; ignoring!]
```

So I tried to uninstall it first. But I got the following error:

```
adb uninstall com.android.providers.media.module
Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]
```

I got the root privilege and remounted the phone, and disabled verity before I did things above.

How can I replace the MediaProvider in Android11 with my own MediaProvider?

Answer (score 0):

com.android.providers.media.module is in directory `/system/apex`. We can build it and then push it to that directory to replace it.